# Bring to front (property) equivalent in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a expander and `TextBlock`.
It at times overlaps for spaces.
I want the expander BringToFront.
But no such property in WPF.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is seems you are using the Canvas Panel for positioning your Expander and TextBlock.

First of all: Don't use a Canvas, it's oldstyle and not flexible enough. Use one of the other Panels (i.e. Grid) to layout your Controls. Then the problem should be gone.

If you must use a Canvas and you want to prevent overlapping, you can use the Panel.ZOrder attached property. You should also set the Background property of the Expander to something opaque like "White". By default the Background property has the null-value, which means transparent.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is a design time issue:

WPF will put the last item in the XAML on top. For instance if I had this:

```
<TextBlock Text="one"/>
<TextBlock Text="Two"/>
```

TextBlock "Two" would be displayed in front of "One" because it is last in the XAML.

If it's a runtime issue bochja had it right up top with the Panel.ZOrder.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to use a Grid, so the element order doesn't matter.

Eg:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding CurrentRequest,ElementName=root}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="These labels"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Will overlap"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Next row"/>
```